# Optimize switch case for dynamic content

Tags: php, optimization

I have written a function for switching advert image based on `$template`. Function is working completely fine without any problem and getting everything dynamically with no issue.

Concerning performance, I want some feedback and suggestion from you experts to optimize code in better way.

Since below code is dynamically getting option key using `$template` so I am not sure is it good to repeat same code for each case or there is some better way.

```
$this->render('<a href="'.option('ops_'.$template.'_advert_destination_link').'" >');
$this->render('<img src="'.option('ops_'.$template.'_advert_image_url').'" alt="adv-'.$template.'-advert" />');
$this->render('</a>');
```

**Please find below is my full function code**

```
function page_advert()
{

    $template = get_request() == '' ? 'home' : get_request_part(0);
    $advert = option('ops_'.$template.'_advert_image_url');

    if((option('ops_'.$template.'_enable_adverts')) && (!empty($advert))) {

        $this->render('<!-- Start page advert -->','<div class="ops-page-advert '.$template.'">'); 

        switch ($template) {
            case 'home':

                $this->render('<a href="'.option('ops_'.$template.'_advert_destination_link').'" >');
                $this->render('<img src="'.option('ops_'.$template.'_advert_image_url').'" alt="adv-'.$template.'-advert" />');
                $this->render('</a>');

                break;

            case 'archive':

                $this->render('<a href="'.option('ops_'.$template.'_advert_destination_link').'" >');
                $this->render('<img src="'.option('ops_'.$template.'_advert_image_url').'" alt="adv-'.$template.'-advert" />');
                $this->render('</a>');

                break;

            case 'page':

                $this->render('<a href="'.option('ops_'.$template.'_advert_destination_link').'" >');
                $this->render('<img src="'.option('ops_'.$template.'_advert_image_url').'" alt="adv-'.$template.'-advert" />');
                $this->render('</a>');

                break;

            case 'contact':

                $this->render('<a href="'.option('ops_'.$template.'_advert_destination_link').'" >');
                $this->render('<img src="'.option('ops_'.$template.'_advert_image_url').'" alt="adv-'.$template.'-advert" />');
                $this->render('</a>');

                break;

            case 'tags':

                $this->render('<a href="'.option('ops_'.$template.'_advert_destination_link').'" >');
                $this->render('<img src="'.option('ops_'.$template.'_advert_image_url').'" alt="adv-'.$template.'-advert" />');
                $this->render('</a>');

                break;

            case 'categories':

                $this->render('<a href="'.option('ops_'.$template.'_advert_destination_link').'" >');
                $this->render('<img src="'.option('ops_'.$template.'_advert_image_url').'" alt="adv-'.$template.'-advert" />');
                $this->render('</a>');

                break;

            case 'users':

                $this->render('<a href="'.option('ops_'.$template.'_advert_destination_link').'" >');
                $this->render('<img src="'.option('ops_'.$template.'_advert_image_url').'" alt="adv-'.$template.'-advert" />');
                $this->render('</a>');

                break;

            case 'admin':

                $this->render('<a href="'.option('ops_'.$template.'_advert_destination_link').'" >');
                $this->render('<img src="'.option('ops_'.$template.'_advert_image_url').'" alt="adv-'.$template.'-advert" />');
                $this->render('</a>');

                break;

            default:                    
                return false;
                break;
        }

        $this->render('</div>', '<!-- End page advert -->');

    } //endif

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ah! what a stupid mistake I have done.. :P Didn't realized that I don't have to use Switch Case either. Here is the final optimized code

```
function page_advert()
{

    $template = get_request() == '' ? 'home' : get_request_part(0);
    $advert = option('ops_'.$template.'_advert_image_url');

    if((option('ops_'.$template.'_enable_adverts')) && (!empty($advert))) {

        $html = '
        <!-- Start page advert -->
        <div class="q2am-page-advert '.$template.'">
            <a href="'.option('ops_'.$template.'_advert_destination_link').'" >
                <img src="'.option('ops_'.$template.'_advert_image_url').'" alt="adv-market-'.$template.'-advert" />
            </a>
        </div>
        <!-- End page advert -->
        ';

        $this->output($html);

    } //endif

}
```

Comment: Why not concatenate all of those lines of HTML and just make 1 render call?

Comment: @jsanc623 how about this now?

Comment: looks much better now and only 1 function call vs 5 :)